# Java подключение библиотеки в cmd

Tags: java, jar

Компилирую файл java по пути `"C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.2\webapps\kursa\WEB-INF\classes\Ping.java"` чтоб он скомпилировался нужно подключить стороний jar который находится

```
"C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.2\l
ib\servlet-api.jar"
```

как правильно сделать это в консольной строке windows?

Comment: Посмотрите эту тему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javac -cp "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.2\l ib\servlet-api.jar" "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.2\webapps\kursa\WEB-INF\classes\Ping.java"`